# Fortran-C interoperability and float arrays

Tags: c, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I have a large existing Fortran95 code. It uses

```
real(dp), dimension(num) :: array
```

to declare arrays.

I want to  join in some C code and found that I can do this by writing interfaces to the C-functions and declaring arrays as

```
use iso_c_binding
real(c_double), allocatable, target :: array(:)
```

I have working fortran functions which call the C-functions as

```
call myfunction(c_loc(array));
```

What is needed to pass the `real(dp)` array to myfunction? Apparently, I would need to make a C-pointer from it (how?). Is there any other way than copying the array? Is it possible to ensure that both types indeed refer to compatible double precision data blocks? Most importantly the solution must work with the GNU compilers. Note, that replacing `real(dp)` with `real(c_double)` everywhere in the existing Fortran code is not an option for me right now.

In case there is no alternative to copying the entire array, how would I do this properly in the interface?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I assume you define dp as a parameter in a module somewhere.  You can simply use

```
integer, parameter :: dp = c_double
```

in that module (and have `if (dp /= c_double) stop "Bletchful sytem"` somewhere.

Passing an array between C and Fortran works like this:

```
module foo
  use iso_c_binding
  private
  public :: bar
  interface
     subroutine bar(a,n) bind(C)
       import
       real(kind=c_double), dimension(*), intent(inout) :: a
       integer(c_size_t), value, intent(in) :: n
     end subroutine bar
  end interface
end module foo
```

Your C function then would be

```
void bar(double *a, size_t n)
```

**Edit:**

The way to call your C function from Fortran would then be

```
program main
  use iso_c_binding
  use foo
  real(c_double), dimension(10) :: a
  call bar(a,size(a,kind=c_size_t))
  print *,a
end program main
```

**Edit 2:**

If you really want to do copy-in / copy-out each time, you can do something like

```
  subroutine bar2(array)
    real(kind=c_double), intent(inout), dimension(:) :: array
    real(kind=c_double), dimension(size(array)) :: a
    a = array  ! Copy in
    call bar(a,size(a,kind=c_size_t))
    array = a  ! Copy out
  end subroutine bar2
end module foo
```

But I am at a loss to understand why this would be necessary.

**Edit 3:**

If you are afraid of a mismatch between C and Fortran datatypes, you can write a generic wrapper to get around this.  This is what it could look like:

```
module foo
  use iso_c_binding
  implicit none
  private
  public :: bar
  interface
     subroutine bar_double(a,n) bind(C)
       import
       real(kind=c_double), dimension(*), intent(inout) :: a
       integer(c_size_t), value, intent(in) :: n
     end subroutine bar_double
  end interface

  interface
     subroutine bar_float(a,n) bind(C)
       import
       real(kind=c_float), dimension(*), intent(inout) :: a
       integer(c_size_t), value, intent(in) :: n
     end subroutine bar_float
  end interface

  interface bar
     module procedure bar_aux_double, bar_aux_float
  end interface bar
contains
  subroutine bar_aux_double (a)
    real(kind=c_double), dimension(:), intent(inout) :: a
    call bar_double (a, size(a,kind=c_size_t))
  end subroutine bar_aux_double

  subroutine bar_aux_float (a)
    real(kind=c_float), dimension(:), intent(inout) :: a
    call bar_float (a, size(a,kind=c_size_t))
  end subroutine bar_aux_float
end module foo
```

Your main program then could look like

```
program main
  use foo
  integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15)
  integer, parameter :: sp = selected_real_kind(6)
  real(dp), dimension(10) :: a_dp
  real(sp), dimension(10) :: a_sp
  call bar(a_dp)
  call bar(a_sp)
  print *,a_dp,a_sp
end program main
```

where you don't make any reference to iso_c_binding at all.  If there is no wrapper function for dp or sp, compilation will fail for lack of a generic procedure.

Comment: Another possibility, depending on other code structure: `use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only : dp => c_double`.

Comment: Thanks, I had considered this. Unfortunately declarations of the array appear in various places and slightly different forms. I am not quite sure if side effects could occur. I am, right now, considering the brute-force method of copying the entire array. In your module foo (which is essentially what I had), how would I add a function which performs the copying and calls the interface subroutine such that it is visible outside? (With contains?)

Comment: To your Edit 2: Assuming that I do not change the type of array in existing fortran and be able to call bar2 with a real(dp) type argument (this is why I would wont to do it), this would not work, because the declaration of array is incompatiple, so how do I convert between the different types when copying?

Comment: What, exactly, is dp in your code?  Is it likely to change (e.g. when going from single precision to double precision) ?

Comment: I have now identified the definition of dp: `integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15, 307)`. What is the definition of c_double?

Comment: For the current gfortran system, this evaluates to 8, which is identical to c_double.  Are you concerned that you will want to change dp at some time, and that the code will break then?

Comment: The concern is more that I am dealing with a large numerical program and I am worried to risk stability when I change the float type (I could impossibly test all possible configurations to exclude that I am introducing an instability somewhere.). Will look at your third edit when I get home!

Comment: Generally, excessive uses of **Edit** headlines is discouraged. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255644/should-edit-in-edits-be-discouraged/255688#255688

Answer (score 1):

If you use modules, don't worry too much when mixing `dp` and `c_double` inside Fortran. In the very unlikely case that `selected_real_kind(15, 307) /= c_double` the compiler will complain when checking the procedure interfaces. Otherwise, it will see that the kind numbers agree and it does not care how you call the kind constant (except when declaring interoperable procedures).

Comment: My initial problem was precisely that the compiler complained when declaring the interfaces for the C-routines and I didn't know how to tell it to convert/ignore the error.

Comment: Just use `c_double` in the interoperable interfaces and `dp` everywhere else. If you have everything in modules, the compiler checks it is OK.